# Why did Edmure Tully do what he did in season 6 episode 8?

Tags: game-of-thrones

**Spoilers for Game of Thrones S06E08**

> Edmure Tully accepted to kill his uncle (he knew this would happen) and to give Riverrun back to the Freys/Lannisters.

I understood that he was afraid Jaime would kill his son & wife, but why did he care about them this much? I'm not a heartless fellow, but given this context:

1. He said he never met this child and never saw his wife again after the wedding night;
2. He was a prisoner of the Freys since the Red Wedding, so he was probably very mad with them;
3. The existence of said son could easily be a lie;
4. His marriage was arranged, it was purely political, he did not love his wife. In fact, as I remember, he just met her right before the wedding (on the same day, or just a few days prior);

Why would he choose the

> lives of his son and wife over his uncle's and his family sovereignty?

Comment: Don't forget that the Tully forces are much more needed for fighting in Winterfell than needed to sit-around in the Riverlands. Ceding the castle made that happen. Brienne possibly told him as such? But, it'd be pretty cool if Jamie slaughtered the retreating Tully forces.

Comment: @konishiki I don't think the Tully forces will be allowed to go freely anywhere they want. Edmure himself is still a prisoner, so I guess his army will be forced to obey the Lannisters/Freys.

Comment: @konishiki - I agree with Joao.  If the Blackfish would have agreed to Biranne's requests by nightfall, Jamie would have honored his agreement, or so he claimed.

That did not happen, so Jamie acted to take the castle by his own methods.  The troops were disarmed and taken as prisoners of war.  They are not free to go anywhere, and they are no help in a war with no weapons.

Comment: Did you *see* [his wife](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Roslin_Tully)? (Season 3, episode 9.) Hawt!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Edmure likely sees no other option. His is a broken man who has spent the past couple of years locked away in terrible conditions.

Jaime is offering him an out from all this. He says to Edmure (paraphrasing right now)"if you do this, you will be moved to Casterly Rock and treated like the noble prisoner you are". (This would be like how Theon is treated by the Starks in the early seasons).

A full summary of Edmure's options:

1. **Decline Jaime's offer**

   - Be sent back to the Frey's and be treated like scum and horrible living conditions
   - Have his wife and son be murdered. (Although he has not seen them, they are innocents in this conflict)
   - Jaime seizes Riverrun anyway and kills everyone

---

2. **Accept Jaime's offer**

   - Be sent to Casterly Rock and treated like a noble prisoner
   - Wife and child come to no harm.
   - All members in the castle are spared as well. (We do see Jaime wanted to take the Blackfish prisoner, but the Blackfish decided not to be taken alive)

---

3. **Betray Jaime** (go into the Riverrun and side with the Blackfish)

   - Have his wife and son be murdered.
   - Jaime seizes Riverrun and kills everyone...

Comment: It's not obvious that Jamie will seize Riverrun. Riverrun is a strong castle with provision enough for a couple of years. Many interesting things can happen during these years: the winter can harm LAnnisters and Freys who lives in tents during the siege. Greyjoys can attack Lannisport,, Dany can return with dragons

Comment: @Schullz exactly what I thought. Blackfish was really confident he could stand the siege (for at least 2 years), so maybe Edmure could have betrayed Jaime and sided with his uncle and both would survive. This was his only chance at freedom, I think, but at the expense of the lives of his wife and child.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because of your first paragraph. He is a broken man, probably believing this war against the Lannisters is a lost cause, and betraying Jaime and siding with his uncle would result in fighting the Lannisters/Freys and killing his wife and son. So he chose to save the Tully army and his family at the expense of only one life: his uncle, and he even gave him the chance to flee.

Comment: @Schullz Riverrun being strong does not mean bugger all if it is surrounded  on all sides with no prospect of relief or help on any point of compass. Jaime made it clear to Edmure that he doesn't care how many men die in storming the walls if that gets him to Cersei. Lannisters had the men and resources to starve Tullys out or Storm the walls. Winter has not set fully in Riverlands yet, there is no Snow still, south of the neck. All other prospects you mentioned are far-fetched and unlikely when you think as a Westerosi Commander.

Comment: @JoãoVictorOliveira Blackfish was an old man with no other hope in life except an honorable death. He had no wife, no kids, no lands. He never said he would survive the siege for 2 years, he only said he had provisions to live besieged for two years, meaning Lannisters would have to storm and give Tully the death he wanted. Edmure was far from a broken man, he was just a man. He did what any dad would do for his kid. If Edmure and his kid die, House Tully dies with them. But if they survive, there is still hope for regaining Riverrun.

Comment: @Aegon there is snow south of the Neck - it can be seen in the Eyerie, when young Arren destroys Sansa's snow castle (maybe it is because Eyerie is too high). Also, all can be sure that there will be winter in Riverlands and it will be soon http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/The_Effects_of_Winter/

Comment: @Schullz I am talking from Show's perspective, not books. I know in books it was snowing in riverrun when Jaime took it. From show, can you cite any example of winter coming to riverlands? I did not see any snow there. And the question is about show as well

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought, do you guys think Edmure was aggrieved that his uncle was ready to let the Freys slit his throat and made no attempt to save his life so felt to think of himself in response? Ofcourse the Freys attempt to kill Edmure was a bluff but may have traumatised him none the less. Plus he is a broken man so all sense of loyalty and fight was thrown out of the window! Just a thought.

Comment: This should be asked as a new question, however, for what it's worth I think not. Edmure is a bit of an idiot, but he's not dumb. He knows the Blackfish and knows that Blackfish can see the empty threats the Freys were making. It was absolutely ridiculous of them to have threatened Edmure's life to begin with since Edmure was their only bargaining chip. Also, why slit someone's throat when you've got them ready to hang? No, empty threat! Both Blackfish and Edmure knew this. **Edmure only changed his mind and followed Jamie's orders *after* his wife and child were threatened.**

Comment: @curious I thought about that as well, but I dismissed it because I believe Edmure would understand his uncle's motives.

Answer (score 2):

Edmure just did the same as Ned Stark at the end, he didn't try to save himself or get a better life in Casterly Rock, he just saved his son, an innocent baby, knowing that Riverrun couldn't win that battle anyway.
Nothing is black or White here, I liked the Blackfish but the last episode he acted as a fool, who didn't care about his family or his men, he only wanted to die his way. The Blackfish in the book didn't act that way.
I would love to see him free again and get his revenge, I dont think that any other character deserve it more than him.