# Game of Thrones - [Spoilers for S6] Would Jon Snow army be capable of freeing Riverrun from the siege?

Tags: game-of-thrones

**Spoilers for Season 6 Episodes 8-9**

Given the events of episode 9,

> Jon Snow winning the Battle of the Bastards and retrieving Winterfell for the Starks,

and assuming Edmure didn't surrender his army and castle to Jaime, would Jon's army be capable freeing Riverrun from the siege laid by the Freys and the Lannisters?

I mean, of course there's no way Edmure could have antecipated that, but let's assume he had betrayed Jaime and stayed inside the walls with his uncle, would Jon Snow & gang be capable of freeing them?

([Linked question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131776/why-did-edmure-tully-do-what-he-did-in-season-6-episode-8))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignorning that this is a speculative question which may result into opinion based answers, The answer is a solid No.

### The dangerous Line of advance

Jon Snow's Army would have to march all the way down south through Moat Calin. There they will need to cross the river Trident either from the Twins or from Ruby ford.

Freys would most likely learn of this advance and alert the besiegers. Jaime would then move to Ruby Ford, forcing the Starks to fight either the strong fortifications of Twins or break themselves on Ruby Ford like Roose Bolton broke himself there against Tywin Lannister when Robb came south.

Ignore the positions of Armies on this map, it is just a map I created for another answer, But as you can see Jon will have to follow Kingsroad southwards and then to reach riverrun, he has to cross the river some how.

[image]

### Uncertain hold on North

They have won the castle of Winterfell but war is far from over. They have to consolidate their rule. There are many houses in North who willingly supported the Boltons, chief among them are powerful houses of Umbers and Karstarks. Jon first needs to consolidate his rule on the Northmen which will be especially tough because Northmen or any Westerosi people have never had a bastard as King. There would be many who will doubt his ability to rule.

### Riverlords and Wildlings

The River lords who might otherwise rise for Sansa or Robin Arryn may rise up against Jon because he is bringing wildlings with him. The Lords of the Seven kingdoms have nothing but contempt for the Wildlings. The prospects of an uprising are also slim because Jon is the Lord of Winterfell instead of Sansa who is a granddaughter of Lord Hoster Tully

### Jon's lack of resources and men

More importantly, Jon does not have the number or resources. Jon has only 2,000 something men and most of them are wildlings who are untrained in ways of pitched battle against armoured and mounted foes. Jaime has all the power of Casterly Rock and Twins. Do you honestly think he could break the siege?

Arryns came to help Sansa. Jon is nothing to them and they did not come to help him. Sansa is cousin of Lord Arryn (And of course Petyr Baelish sees prospects of advantage in helping her).

If Jon marches south anyways and leaves North undefended once again, who is to say that Ironborn might not descend once again or those who have reasons to resent his rule would not rise up in Rebellion? What happens if the monarch on Iron Throne decides to support those who rise up?

### Claim of Arryns on Riverlands

Robin Arryn is also a claimant to Riverlands as Lord Hoster Tully was his grandfather too & his claim will be more acceptable for Riverlords than Sansa's because he is a male. Jon won with help of Arryns but while Arryns helped Sansa gain the North, will they help her to relieve Riverrun and win over Riverlords to her side? I don't think so. I would claim Riverrun for my own if I were a grandson of Lord Hoster Tully.

### Edmure's claim? Lol

Ignore Edmure and his claim, in case of an attack by Arryns and Stark, Edmure would be killed by Freys to ensure their claim to Riverrun.

If as you suggest, had he betrayed Jaime and stayed inside with Blackfish, that would mean end of House Tully. Jaime has enough men to storm the walls and take the castle quickly. He has made it clear he does not care how many men die. The only thing holding his hands is his vow to Catelyn Stark about not raising arms against House Tully or Stark. Blackfish, Edmure and his son are last of the Tullys. Blackfish is an on old man with no kids and nothing to live for. Edmure is a father. He had to make sure that Tullys survived, because if they were wiped in a stupid show of defiance, all hope of regaining Riverrun will be lost. He did not surrender because he was a coward, he surrendered because the fight was hopeless and he was a father.

### Jaime's Experience

Jaime has turned into a cautious commander, he now gives attention to posting outriders. He won't be surprised by anyone now like he was surprised by Robb in Whispering woods.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer @Aegon but I disagree this is purely an opinion based answer. You gave **a lot** of facts to support it. I had no idea Winterfell was so far away from Riverrun, for example.
My question is indeed speculative, but I didn't know this was forbidden. For that I appologise. Should I remove the question?

Comment: @JoãoVictorOliveira Anything which has not yet occurred in canon can be termed as opinion-based because we do not have author's word on the matter so we draw our own observations. Your post is always yours, you can do what you want with it but if you delete a certain number of posts which have answers (voted answers) that can lead to consequences such as revocation of question-privilege.